# How do I change the highlight color style of the code in the IPython(Jupyter)?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, pygments, qtconsole

My question is showed in the following picutre. I want to change the highlight color style of the code region that is specified by the red rectangle in the picutre below. But I dont' know which token I should change style of.

[image]

My pygment style setting code is below

```
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.token import Keyword, Name, Comment, String, Error, \
     Number, Operator, Generic, Whitespace, Token


class EmacsStyle(Style):
    """
    The default style (inspired by Emacs 22).
    """

    background_color = "#333333"
    highlight_color = "#a7a695"
    default_style = ""

    styles = {
        Token:                     "#ffffff",
        Whitespace:                "#bbbbbb",
        Comment:                   "italic #008800",
        Comment.Preproc:           "noitalic",
        Comment.Special:           "noitalic bold",

        Keyword:                   "bold #B541FF",
        Keyword.Pseudo:            "nobold",
        Keyword.Type:              "bold #00BB00",

        Operator:                  "#666666",
        Operator.Word:             "bold #AA22FF",

        Name.Builtin:              "#B541FF",
        Name.Function:             "#00A000",
        Name.Class:                "#4242FF",
        Name.Namespace:            "bold #4242FF",
        Name.Exception:            "bold #D2413A",
        Name.Variable:             "#B8860B",
        Name.Constant:             "#880000",
        Name.Label:                "#A0A000",
        Name.Entity:               "bold #999999",
        Name.Attribute:            "#BB4444",
        Name.Tag:                  "bold #008000",
        Name.Decorator:            "#AA22FF",

        String:                    "#BB4444",
        String.Doc:                "italic",
        String.Interpol:           "bold #BB6688",
        String.Escape:             "bold #BB6622",
        String.Regex:              "#BB6688",
        String.Symbol:             "#B8860B",
        String.Other:              "#008000",
        Number:                    "#666666",

        Generic.Heading:           "bold #4242FF",
        Generic.Subheading:        "bold #B541FF",
        Generic.Deleted:           "#D2413A",
        Generic.Inserted:          "#00A000",
        Generic.Error:             "#FF0000",
        Generic.Emph:              "italic",
        Generic.Strong:            "bold",
        Generic.Prompt:            "bold #4242FF",
        Generic.Output:            "#888",
        Generic.Traceback:         "#04D",

        Error:                     "border:#FF0000"
    }
```

Comment: That code is highlighted in the kernel, and that particular bit of highlighting is not yet done by pygments, so it can't easily be configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a IPython magic command to change the color (on Mac):

```
%colors NoColor
```

or (on Linux)

```
%colors Linux
```

This is not a perfect resolution but works.