# How to change monokai pygments style in qtconsole with jupyter

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, pygments, qtconsole

How does one change monokai pygments style such that errors are printed in lighter colours in jupyter qtconsole when using python?

See the attached screenshot and especially notice how the error type (AttributeError) is in darkish red, function parameters, class/module separators and brackets are in an unreadable darkish blue and even keywords could use lighter green in the traceback.

[jupyter qtconsole with monokai and python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTO1r.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This [How do I change the highlight color style of the code in the IPython(Jupyter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488781/how-do-i-change-the-highlight-color-style-of-the-code-in-the-ipythonjupyter?rq=1) seems to provide a reasonable alternative. Using `%colors Linux` changes how a stacktrace is syntax highlighted and still keeping my molokai style working for the rest of the code.